# Why is my object see-through in solid view

Tags: modeling, objects

In solid view, my object looks as though it is wireframe. I tried to change up the settings in the viewport display under object properties but nothing I did worked. Please someone help me.[image]

Comment: Does this also happen in other files? You could try resetting your blender by going to *File* -> *Defaults* -> *Load Factory Settings* and see if the issue persists.

Comment: That's weird. Do your object have actual faces ? Please try to select 4 vertices and press F (in Edit mode), just to be sure